# The definition of the exchange lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image: a]

We've just learnt about the exchange lemma, and I was looking at someone else's notes - I don't understand the point 2. How can $\psi_t \in \{\psi_1,...,\psi_n \}$? Should it not be in $\{\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n\}$?

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's most probably a typo. What book is that?  +1

Comment: It's not a book, just some notes I found online - sorry for asking such a basic question, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything important. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, fine. My advice is that you continue the search: the above is not, imo, the best way to present the very important exchange  Theorem, typo aside.

Comment: Any recommendations? I'm looking at the proof, and I can barely follow it, perhaps I just don't understand the exchange lemma.

Comment: Try even Wikipedia, @Warz, or http://books.google.co.il/books?id=Zjv5J3882LwC&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=exchange+theorem+linear+algebra&source=bl&ots=T0Jm7OPjox&sig=R1xWmIfgFQkMC1dpofTkl6tRTvw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cirYUubGO9CThQeGyoHYCw&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=exchange%20theorem%20linear%20algebra&f=false , or http://www.pancratz.org/notes/LinearAlgebra.pdf , theorem 1.5 , etc.